# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/1613-0204/Android/data/abcabc_03-00-34.jpeg
```

I am having below code

```
 public static Uri getUriwrtFileProvider(Context mContext, File file) {
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                file);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
    return uri;
}
```

Manifest :

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
 </paths>
```

Unable to track what went wrong . Please point out what am i missing here .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already included read write to grant URI permission.

Comment: is it something kinda external internal storage access issue ?